# Why am I not allowed to give my function parameters?

Tags: c++

I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong here, but putting any parameters into my attempt function gives me an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int guesses = 0;

int attempt(int guess) {
    if(guesses > 0) {
           cout << "Take a guess!";
           cout << endl;
           cin >> guess;
           }
}

int main() {

    int answer = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    int guess;

    srand(time(0));    

    cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. Try to guess it in 3 attempts!";
    cout << endl;
    attempt();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I should add that I'm a beginner, so please explain this to me like a 5 year old.

Comment: A very basic, 5yo type question: what error do you get?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ELI5, does it?

Comment: `int attempt(int guess)` should be `int attempt(int& guess)`, and in main, `attempt();` should pass a `int&`. It's better to learn basics of C++ before writing code.

Comment: "Too few arguments to function"

Comment: `int guesses = 0;`  ... `if(guesses > 0) { ...` And `guesses` isn't modified anywhere.  Nothing within the `attempt()` function will execute, ever.

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest getting a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I actually do have a couple of books, I've read them all more than once too, I'm just in the process of trying to pick up where I left off a few months back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a function with value parameters, such as

```
void func(int i)
```

you are declaring *inputs*.

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int i)
{
    // the 'i' you see here is a local variable.
    i = 10;
    // we changed the local thing called 'i', when
    // we exit in a moment that 'i' will go away.
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    func(i);
    // if we print 'i' here, it will be our version of i.
    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The `i` parameter to `func` is local to `func`; this confuses new C++ programmers especially in the above scenario, it looks like you are passing `i` itself into func rather than passing *the value of main::i*.

As you get further into C/C++ you'll discover 'reference' and 'pointer' types which allow you to actually forward variables to functions rather than their values.

When your function is actually doing is fetching a user input value and then passing that back to the caller, or returning it.

```
int attempt()
{
    std::cout << "Take a guess!\n";

    int guess;
    std::cin >> guess;

    return guess;
}
```

We tell the compiler that "attempt" takes no arguments and will *return* an int value. Then at the end of the function we use `return` to do exactly that.

`return` can only pass back one value - again, later you will learn about pointers and references, which will allow you to return something larger than a single value.

To receive this value to your main:

```
int main() {

    int answer = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    srand(time(0));    

    std::cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. Try to guess it in 3 attempts!";
    std::cout << endl;

    int guess = attempt();
    std::cout << "You guessed: " << guess << '\n';

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can break the variable declaration and use into two lines:

```
int guess;
...
guess = attempt;
```

A key thing to take away from all this is that you can have different variables with the same name in different 'scopes':

```
int i = 1;  // global, visible to all functions in this compilation unit.

int main()
{
    srand(time());
    int i = 2;

    if ((rand() % 4) == 0) // 1 in four chance
    {
         // this is essentially a new scope.
         int i = 10;
    }

    // here, i = 2.
}

void foo()
{
    // here, i = 1 - we see the global since we didn't declare our own.
}

void foo2(int i)
{
    // here, i is whatever value we were called with.
    if (i == 1)
    {
        int i = 99;
    }
    // we're back to the i we were called with.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd be better off with something like:

```
int attempt() {
    int guess;
    cout << "Take a guess!\n";
    cin >> guess;
    return guess;
}
```

and *calling* it with:

```
guess = attempt();
```

There's no point in passing the current `guess` into attempt and it would only be reflected back to the caller if it were a reference parameter, which it isn't.

I'm also not *entirely* certain what you were hoping to gain by only asking for a guess when guesses had already been made but that was the effect of your old code.

Other issues you may have:

You call `rand` before `srand`. That means you'll get the same random number on each run since the behaviour of `rand` where no seed has been set is as if you'd called `srand(1)`.

The `guesses` variable is set to zero and never changed. Presumably you'll fix this when you get around to implementing the "three guesses only" functionality (with a loop in `main` presumably).

Answer (score 0):

1. You function

   ```
   int attempt(int guess)
   ^^^
   ```

   need to return a `int` value.
2. When you call this function in main body, call it properly with input parameters, so change

   ```
   attempt();
   ```

   to

   ```
   attempt(guess);
   ```

Comment: While certainly a good point, this isn't a guaranteed error. It's typically a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared as

```
int attempt(int guess);
```

that is it has 1) to accept an argument of type int and 2) to return an object of type int.

And 1) it is called without an argument

```
attempt();
```

2) and does not return any object of type int.